# how to get the result from database in following format in php

Tags: php, mysql

Looking for sql query which will solve the following query. I have table employees with following fields:

```
sno                name                       managerid
1                        a                       2
2                        b                       3
3                        c                       4
```

and so on.

Now I want to display the data in the following way:

```
 name                       managername
    a                                b
    b                                c
    c                                d
```

How to do this using PHP and MySQL?

Comment: You have to use self join

Comment: self join `select t1.name,t2.name as manager_name from table_name t1 left join table_name t2 on t2.managerid = t1.id`

Comment: "Looking for sql query" - bear in mind that we are here to help, not to do your work for you. If you can add in an attempt when asking questions, this helps greatly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query which has self join.

```
select
  t1.name, t2.name As managername
from
  table_name t1
inner join table_name t2 
  on t1.managerid = t2.sno
```

Hope this will work